# Como remover opção de download de vídeo

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-video

Gostaria de remover as opções de download do vídeo (Eu sei que isso não impedirá o download dele através de outros meios. Mas a ideia é apenas dificultar isso para usuários mais leigos).

Tenho o seguinte exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/n0ng38eo/

Onde através de CSS eu consigo esconder o botão de download do vídeo.

Mas caso o usuário clique com o botão direito do mouse, ele ainda tem a opção de baixar o vídeo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de remover essa opção também via javascript ou algum tipo de configuração HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei uma solução: https://jsfiddle.net/u1wqb4kz/

```css
// Remove botão de download de vídeos
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

```html
<video src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" oncontextmenu="return false;" controls></video>
```

Usei uma das respostas dessa página do [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Comment: Muito bem, dai ele entra na pagina com Google Chrome, exibe o código fonte, clica no link do video e a famigerada janelinha aparece para ele fazer o download.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo na pergunta eu disse que a ideia não era impedor o download do vídeo. Até pq isso é praticamente impossível. Por mais sofisticado q fosse o método eu poderia usar um programa e gravar o mesmo quando ele estivesse sendo reproduzido na tela. Eu queria apenas desabilitar essa opção para usuários leigos. No link do stackoverflow q eu encontrei a solução, existem métodos mais avançados também. Mas para o q eu precisava isso bastou.

Comment: Entendi, mas o ideal então seria impedir usuários leigos, pouco leigos, mais ou menos leigos e leigos. Deixar a brecha só para usuários espertos! A minha resposta abrange toda classe de leigos. :)

Comment: Editei a resposta e trouxe o código pra cá, se um dia o jsfiddle ficar offline por manutenção, ataque ou urls antigas forem removidas você terá a segurança do código estar a salvo também na resposta. +1 pra sua resposta

Answer (score 1):

Já que é para dificultar além da solução  do próprio autor da pergunta, pode-se colocar esse script que inibe direito do mouse e muito mais.

```js
function bloqueia_mouse_teclado() {

        // CTRL V v
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '118' || event.which == '86')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL C c
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '97' || event.which == '67')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL U u
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '85' || event.which == '117')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL A a
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '65' || event.which == '97')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL S s
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '83' || event.which == '115')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL X x
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '88' || event.which == '120')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        // CTRL J j
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '74' || event.which == '106')) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });



        // Bloquear botão direito do mouse
        $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
            return false;
        });
    }


    bloqueia_mouse_teclado();
```

```css
// Remove botão de download de vídeos
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" oncontextmenu="return false;" controls></video>
```

Comment: Além de bloquear o botão direito do mouse. O que mais este script bloqueia?

Comment: no próprio código tem os comentários do que inibe. Essa propriedade oncontextmenu="return false; parece não funcionar no Opera

Answer (score -2):

Olá. Você pode usar isso, mas desde já, não remove a opção de download através do botão direito do mouse.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <video id="videoPlayer" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
    </body>
    </html>
```